# SQL order by 2 date columns

Tags: sql

I have a table with orders. Each order has a `delivery_date`, and a `collection_date`.

I want to retrieve the orders as a schedule for a week which shows what the next thing is to do.

So I guess I want the time sequence shown so that a collection on Wednesday appears in between a delivery on Tuesday and another delivery on Thursday.

Any ideas on how to do this with SQL?

Comment: What datbase are you using? MySQL, Oracle? MSSQL? SQLite? They handle date data differently and with differenly-named functions. Any answer will probably be dependent on a specific vendor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using a Union ALL, I'm treating each of your order records as two records: one for a delivery and one for a collection. If you had another date (repair?), you would union another sub query with similar fields.

I made up a lot of this since you did not provide any specs on your order table.

```
select *
from (
   Select OrderID
       , 'Colection' as VisitType
      , Collection_Date as VisitDate
   from Orders
   Union All
   Select OrderID
     , 'Delivery' as VisitType
     , Delivery_Date as VisitDate
  from Orders
) as v
order by v.VisitDate
```

Comment: Thank you also for your reply. I will try both of these and see which suits best. Possibly this one as it merges the two dates under one name in the results. So I guess I need to put a check in my code so the same order doesnt get shown twice ?

Comment: IVe learnt alot from this thanks a lot have perfect behaviour now :)

Answer (score 8):

Depending on which database you're using, it'll be something along the lines of

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN delivery_date > collection_date 
         THEN collection_date ELSE delivery_date END
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is it possible to label the dates as another name like 'DT_THE_DATE' whether its the collection date or the delivery date?

Comment: @user1383132: MySql has a case statement (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html) -- I'm sure you can translate it.