# How to order rows by the greatest date of each row, for a table with 8 date columns?

Tags: sql, mariadb, sql-order-by

This is very different from doing an [SQL order by 2 date columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506843/sql-order-by-2-date-columns) (or for [proper way to sort sql columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24223098/proper-way-to-sort-sql-columns), which is only for 1 column). There, we would do something like:

```sql
ORDER BY CASE WHEN date_1 > date_2 
         THEN date_2 ELSE date_1 END
```

FYI, I'm using `YYY-MM-DD` in this example for brevity, but I also need it to work for
`TIMESTAMP` (`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS`)

I have this table:

| id | name | date_1 | date_2 | date_3 | date_4 | date_5 | date_6 | date_7 | date_8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 2008-08-11 | 2008-08-12 | 2009-08-11 | 2009-08-21 | 2009-09-11 | 2017-08-11 | 2017-09-12 | 2017-09-30 |
| 2 | Bill | 2008-09-12 | 2008-09-12 | 2008-10-12 | 2011-09-12 | 2008-09-13 | 2022-05-20 | 2022-05-21 | 2022-05-22 |
| 3 | Andy | 2008-10-13 | 2008-10-13 | 2008-10-14 | 2008-10-15 | 2008-11-01 | 2008-11-02 | 2008-11-03 | 2008-11-04 |
| 4 | Hank | 2008-11-14 | 2008-11-15 | 2008-11-16 | 2008-11-17 | 2008-12-31 | 2009-01-01 | 2009-01-02 | 2009-01-02 |
| 5 | Alex | 2008-12-15 | 2018-12-15 | 2018-12-15 | 2018-12-16 | 2018-12-17 | 2018-12-18 | 2018-12-25 | 2008-12-31 |

... But, the permutations of that give me a headache, just to think about them.

[This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2959346/10343144) had more of a "general solution", but that was to `SELECT`, not to `ORDER BY`...

```sql
SELECT MAX(date_col)
FROM(
  SELECT MAX(date_col1) AS date_col FROM some_table
  UNION
  SELECT MAX(date_col2) AS date_col FROM some_table
  UNION
  SELECT MAX(date_col3) AS date_col FROM some_table
  ...
)
```

Is there something more like that, such as could be created by iterating a loop in, say PHP or Node.js? I need something a *scalable* solution.

- I only need to list each `row` once.
- I want to order them each by whichever `col` has the most recent date of those I list on that `row`.

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE
(
  GREATEST OF date_1
  OR date_2
  OR date_3
  OR date_4
  OR date_5
  OR date_6
  OR date_7
  OR date_8
)
```

Comment: mariadb supports [GREATEST](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/greatest/) function, you can use that. `GREATEST(date_1,date_2,date_3,date_4,date_5,date_6,date_7,date_8)`.

Comment: Try here: [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=764b61bf66f637603ea13316fb301f5d)

Comment: @Abinash I'd love an Answer to vote on and mark correct!

Comment: @Abinash Can you show me how that works in an `ORDER BY` statement?

Comment: Numbered columns col_1, col_2, etc., are usually indication for a bad data modeling.

Comment: Of course. It's just for this example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `GREATEST` function to achieve it.

```
SELECT  GREATEST(date_1,date_2,date_3,date_4,date_5,date_6,date_7,date_8) max_date,t.*
FROM Tab t
ORDER BY GREATEST(date_1,date_2,date_3,date_4,date_5,date_6,date_7,date_8) Desc;
```

DB Fiddle: [Try it here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=764b61bf66f637603ea13316fb301f5d)

| max_date | id | name | date_1 | date_2 | date_3 | date_4 | date_5 | date_6 | date_7 | date_8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-22 | 2 | Bill | 2008-09-12 | 2008-09-12 | 2008-10-12 | 2011-09-12 | 2008-09-13 | 2022-05-20 | 2022-05-21 | 2022-05-22 |
| 2018-12-25 | 5 | Alex | 2008-12-15 | 2018-12-15 | 2018-12-15 | 2018-12-16 | 2018-12-17 | 2018-12-18 | 2018-12-25 | 2008-12-31 |
| 2017-09-30 | 1 | John | 2008-08-11 | 2008-08-12 | 2009-08-11 | 2009-08-21 | 2009-09-11 | 2017-08-11 | 2017-09-12 | 2017-09-30 |
| 2009-01-02 | 4 | Hank | 2008-11-14 | 2008-11-15 | 2008-11-16 | 2008-11-17 | 2008-12-31 | 2009-01-01 | 2009-01-02 | 2009-01-02 |
| 2008-11-04 | 3 | Andy | 2008-10-13 | 2008-10-13 | 2008-10-14 | 2008-10-15 | 2008-11-01 | 2008-11-02 | 2008-11-03 | 2008-11-04 |

Comment: Could you mention that `GREATEST` is for mariadb? And, I'd welcome another Answer from you or anyone that can work with MySQL.

Comment: `GREATEST` works in MySQL too.  [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=764b61bf66f637603ea13316fb301f5d)

Comment: If you decided that you want the `greatest` expression in the `select` clause, there is no need to duplicate it for the `order by` clause. `SELECT  GREATEST(date_1,date_2,date_3,date_4,date_5,date_6,date_7,date_8) max_date,t.*
FROM Tab t
ORDER BY max_date Desc;`

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz Thanks! I'd love an Answer to vote on.

Answer (score 1):

In the event of a `NULL` value, `GREATEST` could throw-off the `ORDER`.

Based on [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35261783/10343144) from a Question about `GREATEST` handling `NULL`, this would apply these tables, based on the approved Answer:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE (
  GREATEST(date_1,date_2,date_3,date_4,date_5,date_6,date_7,date_8),
  date_1,date_2,date_3,date_4,date_5,date_6,date_7,date_8 
) max_date,t.*
FROM TAB t
ORDER BY COALESCE (
  GREATEST(date_1,date_2,date_3,date_4,date_5,date_6,date_7,date_8),
  date_1,date_2,date_3,date_4,date_5,date_6,date_7,date_8
) DESC;
```